# Strip known extension from filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a bunch of txt files. I want to strip out the `.txt` from the filename (which I am reading via `os.walk`).

How could I achieve this?

`fileName.rstrip(".txt")` seems to remove the letters `.`,`t`,`x` rather than removing the substring `.txt`

Comment: Both `filename.split('.')[0]` and `filename[:-4]` should do the trick.

Comment: What about fileName.split(".")[:-1] ?

Comment: Splitting at '.' would work if '.' is used only to separate the filename from extension. But that's not guaranteed. There could be multiple '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomment using the OS library.

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rpartition` (`partition` from right), and get the first elemnet from resulting tuple:

```
fileName.rpartition(".txt")[0]
```

`rpartition` is guaranteed to generate a 3-element tuple in the form:

```
(before, sep, after)
```

So, for filenames with `.txt` extension e.g. `foobar.txt` you would get:

```
('foobar', '.txt', '')
```

For files that does not end with `.txt` e.g. `foobar`:

```
('foobar', '', '')
```

so getting the first element would work in all cases.

Comment: Files that do not end with `.txt`, e.g. `foobar`, will look like `('', '', 'foobar')`.

Comment: @olliezhu You used `rpartition`, try `partition` (note the `r` (right) prefix is not there).